# Razor - Binding a collection of abstract class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding

I have the following model that I am trying to bind with razor:

```
public abstract class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class TextQuestion : Question
{
    public string Response { get; set; }
}

public class RadioQuestion : Question
{
    public string[] Options { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
    
public class SampleViewModel
{
    public Question[] Questions { get; set; }
}
```

When iterating over the collection, I'm not sure how to bind the collection as when I cast the questions to their specific type, I lose the array index value in the HTML:

```
if(Model.Questions[question] is TextQuestion)
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => (Model.Questions[question] as TextQuestion).Response, Model.Questions[question].Text)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => (Model.Questions[question] as TextQuestion).Response, new {@class="form-control"}) 
    </div>  
}
            
if(Model.Questions[question] is RadioQuestion)
{
    for(var option = 0; option < (Model.Questions[question] as RadioQuestion).Options.Length; option++)
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => (Model.Questions[question] as RadioQuestion).Value, (Model.Questions[question] as RadioQuestion).Options[option])
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => (Model.Questions[question] as RadioQuestion).Value, (Model.Questions[question] as RadioQuestion).Options[option])
        </div>  
    }
}
```

I have created a dotnetfiddle here showing that the model binding isn't working: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pQLwl7

I'm curious what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Modelbinder needs to instantiate an instance of a binding target. You cannot instantiate an abstract class so it is not a valid binding target. Try making the Question class non-abstract.

Comment: That doesn't work either, this is what I get as JSON: {"Questions":null}